# Moderator diamond still shows when you flag a post

Tags: bug, flags, design

I just notice that the moderator diamond not hide when you open the flag list :
[image: moderator diamond]

Is this a bug, or it is for purpose?

Comment: Not a bug. The diamond has `z-index: 9999999999999` to celebrate the moderator's glory.

Comment: Guessing it's a z-index thingy coming through....

Comment: @Pekka웃 So the flag dialog should be `z-index: 99999999999999999999` (just to avoid reasonable settings :D).

Comment: No, it needs to stay as a subtle reminder: "you are trying to flag a post that a moderator *already looked at*? Are you *really sure* you want to do that?"

Comment: @Pekka웃 this no happen with `already looked at` it happen also with commets you can check with this post and you will that the diamond of  Jon Clements is not hide

Comment: @YCF_L I'm just joking. It's clearly a UI bug that needs fixing.

Comment: I thought you were serious, @Pekka 웃, because we do still get people flagging questions that have already had a moderator seal of... er... disapproval, on them, asking us to do exactly the thing it says a moderator has done.

Comment: @BoltClock clearly that needs an automated solution; if I flag something demanding an action that has already been taken, the response should be a modal dialog saying `ヽ༼ ಠ益ಠ ༽ﾉ WTF YOU DOING?!?!?!?! ` over and over

Comment: @Pekka웃 and animated in glorious high-fidelity ascii, including table flip.

Comment: @Pekka웃 that should be a feature-request

Comment: @Pekka웃 reminds me of this http://i.stack.imgur.com/rVrDr.png

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Is it fixed already?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293318/flag-dialogue-popup-is-stacked-behind-realtime-post-deleted-notification-banners